# ERROR: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php

Code:

PHP-Version: 7.4.1

Error Line:

```php
if($this->allianceData['ally_owner'] == $USER['id']) {
```

Comment: The error means that your query don't receive a row. then he give a boolean. and you try to access the boolean. You can try this:
`if($this->allianceData['ally_owner'] ?? 'default value' == $USER['id']) {`

Comment: The error message simply means that the value of either `$this->allianceData` OR `$USER` is a boolean and not an array. No other assumptions can be made from what is provided.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your query don't receive a row. then he give a boolean. and you try to access the boolean. You can try this:

`if($this->allianceData['ally_owner'] ?? 'default value' == $USER['id'] ?? 'default value') {`

Since I don't know your entire code, I assume that you have already checked whether the user is authenticated? Either via middleware or in the code above.

Comment: Since the error doesn't specifies the column, the error can either be on `$this->allianceData` or `$USER`

Comment: @EliasSoares You are right! I assumed that the questioner had already checked this. but since I don't know the code, this would also be an option to be intercepted at this point. I have added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are trying to access a value that does not exist in your array, you can try using `print_r($this->allianceData);` and `print_r($USER);` to see how the arrangements are composed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem, the solution for me turned out to be extremely simple and thought I would just note it down to hopefully save someone a bunch of searching for nothing!

If your errors are being displayed in the backend of your site, in a form, on a settings page, this might help you.

Essentially we are requesting an element of an array but in my instance the array was not created yet, I wrote into the fields displaying the error then saved the form. Thus, creating the array, adding the values to the array for future calls. On reload, the page worked!